# Why does this code not work for all inputs

Tags: python

I am trying to write python code that takes two strings as input and checks if all the characters of the second string are present in the first string. If so, then the output is the second string. If not, the output is the string "This does not work". I have tested this procedure for a variety of inputs, and it typically works, but not always. For example, if my two inputs are "helo" and "olhe", respectively, the output is "This does not work," whereas it should be "olhe" since all the characters in "olhe" are present in "helo."

Here is my code

```
def fix_machine(debris,product):
    n = 1
    while True:
          first_element = product[0:n]
          find_first_element = debris.find(first_element)
          if first_element == product:
               return product
               break
          n = n + 1
          if find_first_element == -1:
               return "This does not work"
               break
```

So why does this not work?

Comment: Step through it in the debugger and find out.

Comment: Your indentations have a combination of tabs and spaces. That is a very bad idea in Python. Configure your text editor to use only spaces and correct your code.

Comment: `product[0:n]` yields successively larger pieces of `product`; it does not yield individual characters.

Comment: A few side notes: You describe a generic function, then show your code with a very specific function - at least by name - called `fix_machine`. Are we supposed to conclude that `debris` and `product` are the two input strings??? Because `product[0:n]` sure as hell doesn't help with that conclusion (I'd expect `first_element` to be a single character). You should display a piece of code which aligns with your description, for example, `def check_chars(str1,str2)`. Second, the entire function looks like a very bad method for doing what you've described, which can be implemented in a single line.

Comment: Third, as already mentioned above, debug your code step by step. That's the whole idea behind programming (in opposed to "why does this not work?").

Comment: @Rory Daulton I know that my indentation is not the issue

Comment: It is an issue for those of us trying to execute your code. It made a real mess in my text editor, so I gave up trying to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as a more elegant solution, assuming that you strictly want all of the second string characters to be present in first.

```
def fix_machine(first, second):
    for character in second:
        if character not in first:
            return False
    return second
```

This returns correct input for your code. Not entirely sure what is wrong with your code as I have not stepped through.

EDIT: Albert has a much more elegant solution, reference his

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you just want to compare two strings containing different characters.

For doing so, I would suggest converting both strings to a `set` which then provides (in contrast to a `list`) order-less comparison of its elements.

```
def check_string(first_str, second_str):
    # convert strings to sets in order to compare characters
    if set(first_string) == set(second_string):
        return second_str
    else:
        return 'This does not work.'


first_string = 'helo'
second_string = 'olhe'    
print(check_string(first_string, second_string))
# prints True

first_string = 'helo'
second_string = 'hello'    
print(check_string(first_string, second_string))
# prints True

first_string = 'helo'
second_string = 'helofoo'    
print(check_string(first_string, second_string))
# prints 'This does not work.'
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you should step through that code with a debugger (maybe try PyCharm if you don't have an IDE set up yet) to see what went wrong. Would be hard to explain whats going wrong but I think it has something to do with `first_element = product[0:n]`. This will return increasingly larger segments of the string. i.e. 'ol' on the second run through.

Here's an alternative way of writing it

```
def fix_machine(debris, product):
    all_present = all(letter in debris for letter in product)
    return product if all_present else 'This does not work'
```

Comment: You're missing a `return` at the beginning of that statement.

Comment: @barakmanos I was just doing enough for it to test in the python repl. I'll update it to mimic the OPs function.